# How to write a shell script using command line argument to convert hours to seconds

Tags: scripts

Okay everyone.  I am working on a shell script but I want to use command line arguments instead.

For instance if I enter time 2 hours, the output should be 7200 seconds.  This is what I have so far but it is using the read instead of argument.  How can I rewrite this as command line argument?

```
seconds=0

echo -n "Enter number of seconds : "
read seconds

hours=$((seconds / 3600))
seconds=$((seconds % 3600))
minutes=$((seconds / 60))
seconds=$((seconds % 60))

echo "$hours hour(s) $minutes minute(s) $seconds second(s)"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace `seconds` with `$1`, which will match the first argument passed to the script.

If you want to specify the units of the input, then you can reference `$2` for this. **Note:** I am not able to test the `if` statements right now, syntax may be off:

```
if [ $2 == "minutes" ]; then
    seconds=$(($1*60))
elif [ $2 == "hours" ]; then
    seconds=$(($1*3600))
else
    seconds=$1
fi
hours=$((seconds / 3600))
seconds=$((seconds % 3600))
minutes=$((seconds / 60))
echo "$hours hour(s) $minutes minute(s) $seconds second(s)"
```

Usage:

```
$ ./time.sh 7200
2 hour(s) 0 minute(s) 0 second(s)
$ ./time.sh 2 hours
2 hour(s) 0 minute(s) 0 second(s)
```

Comment: this works perfect:  this is the results but how do I get rid of the $ on the minutes (see where it has 25 then $)             show_seconds_for 102354
28 hour(s) 25$ minute(s) 1554 second(s)

Comment: this works perfect:  this is the results but how do I get rid of the $ on the minutes (see where it has 25 then $)             show_seconds_for 102354
28 hour(s) 25$ minute(s) 1554 second(s)                                                                        On a side note - I know this is crazy but what if I want to specify for instance show_seconds_for 14 minutes or 2 hours.  I know I need some work on this one

Comment: I accidentally had an extra `$` on the end, removed it now. Could you explain more what you mean about showing seconds?

Comment: For instance if I execute the script called show_seconds_for (then followed by just numbers, it works) for instance:  show_seconds_for 6544789 but if I execute show_seconds_for 5 hours, it just populates in the seconds field.  I want to execute both rather I just put in numbers or if I put in 5 hours, it will convert to hours many seconds or populate in the hour field.  hope this make since.  right now if I put 5 hours, it will only populate in the second field and not the hour field

Comment: I added a section to test for units, may need some adjustments to work.

Comment: can you supply what you added.  I still am not getting it.  really need to display hours, minutes into seconds.  for instance,  If I put

Comment: can you supply what you added. I still am not getting it. really need to display hours, minutes into seconds. for instance, If I put:  show_seconds 2 hours
0 hour(s) 0 minute(s) 2 second(s)
It should display 7200 seconds; not 2 seconds. but if I just put numbers like show_seconds 1244
0 hour(s) 20 minute(s) 1244 second(s).  I get correct answer but also put 1244 in second feild.  this is the script i currently have. seconds=$1
hours=$2
minutes=$3
hours=$((seconds / 3600))
seconds=$((seconds % 3600))
minutes=$((seconds / 60))

echo "$hours hour(s) $minutes minute(s) $seconds second(s)"

Comment: want to thank everyone for helping out. This is what I was looking for.                                                                if [ "$2" == "minutes" ]; then
    seconds=$(($1*60))
echo "$seconds second(s)"

else
if [ "$2" == "hours" ]; then
    seconds=$(($1*3600))
echo "$seconds second(s)"
elif [ "$2" == "" ]
then
echo "must specify amount of time"
else
    seconds=$1

echo "$seconds second(s)"

fi
fi